# What should our .com domain name be?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/405/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

Stack Exchange sites will be keeping their sitename.stackexchange.com name. **Due to Stack Exchange's prior agreement with Canonical Ltd., ubuntu.stackexchange.com will receive your  askubuntu.com domain name, as originally agreed.** Some Stack Exchange sites WILL also receive redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/405/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

As per the [7 essential Meta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), we need to pick a domain name for the site.

Please post as answers your proposals for a **.com domain name** for this site.

**Rules:**

- Name must be available (or parked - see comment in blog post)
- Avoid dashes where possible
- .com is the preferred Top Level Domain

**Please do NOT post domains that are being used.**

Comment: Incidentally, refreshing the StackAuth data on StackMobile paid off - I got user ID #5 - not bad!

Comment: lol... I wonder what the chances of someong going and grabbing anything popular here...

Comment: That's not actually legal, FYI.

Comment: Why is it not legal?

Comment: (although Stack Overflow have registered AskUbuntu.com already, presumably to stop someone doing that!)

Comment: bugnumberone.com would be cool and a bit of an in joke, but someone already has it. D'oh.

Comment: This is #1 question on meta!

Answer (score 48):

## ask.ubuntu.com

Comment: Assuming cooperation from Canonical?

Comment: I am sure that if the community wanted to use ask.ubuntu.com, Canonical would not refuse.

Comment: While I'm totally up for this I feel it should be a redirect to an actual domain name (AskUbuntu.com is available and is practically identical).

Comment: Redirecting is ugly.

Comment: @Ross, If anything, the redirect should be the other way around, with AskUbuntu.com going to ask.ubuntu.com.

Comment: @lfaraone: Yes, this is exactly what I was thinking. Do you personally think Canonical would be willing to do this? I'm curious to hear what you think.

Comment: I think strictly it would be the [Ubuntu Community Council](https://launchpad.net/~communitycouncil) (CC) that would decide - see the [Trademark Policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy) for more details. The CC may want to have some formal accountability, maybe the right to select or deselect moderators, as [they can for the ubuntu forums](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ForumsGovernance).

Comment: the second awesomest since qa.ubuntu.com is taken

Comment: @lfarone, My thinking was that since StackExchange would own the domain, and it wouldn't be hosted at ubuntu.com that the ubuntu.com should refer back to the "master" domain (if that makes sense).

Comment: Seeking to use an ubuntu.com subdomain would create needless conflict with Ubuntu Ask. http://ubuntu.shapado.com/

Comment: @moberley:
Woah that site's...it looks just like it's one of these.  Actually, it looks like a FOSS version of SE.  But how would using a ubuntu.com subdomain conflict?  That site doesn't end in .ubuntu.com

Comment: @maco it would be us trying to be the 'official' ask site. Why should we go to *.ubuntu.com when they aren't...

Comment: @maco I used the word "conflict" in the personal rather than technical sense. My understanding is the creator of Ubuntu Ask wanted a Q&A site running free software that could be multilingual. By seeking official status for this site it creates a platform for arguments about closed versus open that are unlikely to be resolved. It seems inconsiderate to go in that direction when there are good alternatives.

Comment: I agree with moberley. This is not an Ubuntu.com site. It should be separate. There is a lot of politics tied up in the existence of this site as it is with arguments about closed / open solutions unix SE / ubuntu SE. ask.ubuntu.com just feels wrong to me.

Comment: Yes, but. It'd be replacing a sucky closed-source solution (VB) with a awesome one. If you don't like it, don't use it, just as we have with the forums.

Comment: @lfaraone: I do like the SE sites and agree they are awesome. My point is that it is separate from Ubuntu.com and using ask.ubuntu.com doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 36):

Ask Ubuntu

## AskUbuntu.com

Available.

Comment: Meh. Sounds like you're asking somebody named Ubuntu something. Confusing.

Comment: It wins and stands.

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu Exchange

## UbuntuExchange.com

Available.

Comment: has my vote so far

Comment: This doesn't have much appeal to me over `ubuntu.stackexchange.com`

Comment: I like this, but I do worry that as stack exchange becomes the next vbulletin, that this will seem stranger and stranger as time goes by.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to put the human element back into this and I realise I have missed the mark a little and it just sounds cheesy but, what about something like

### **MyUbuntuBuddy.com**

(Available)

As in, "I am stuck. I know I'll ask My Ubuntu Buddy."

Or in forum threads you can link to answers on this site by saying

You can find out more from [My Ubuntu Buddy](http://myubuntubuddy.com/example).

It is supposed to feel like you are referring to a good friend who knows about Ubuntu rather than yet another knowledge base site.

Comment: To me there is something very appealing about this compared to the other options presented here.

Comment: @fluteflute: Thanks buddy. Feel free to suggest alternatives on this theme. BTW I just realise you are practically my next door neighbour, I'm in West Sussex.

Comment: I think this suggestion is a victim of coming along too late. The three suggestions 'above' all have downvotes, and in pretty significant quantities. This idea has none...

Comment: There's a special place in hell for those that create popular My* names.

Comment: @Roger, Thankfully I have been saved from that fate. :) I never liked the name either but the idea of referring to the site as a person.

Answer (score 2):

### ubuntu.stackexchange.com

I think that the present domain would be

1. simple to remember
2. good for people who know stackexchange
3. good for SEO (maybe not that useful, since SE sites are well indexed)
4. a nice precedent (repeating points 1,2,3 for the other SE sites going beyond beta stage)

Comment: No, these subdomains are exclusively for the purpose of holding the beta. They are not intended to be permanent.

Comment: Perhaps is something changeable? "A mind is like a parachute. It doesn't work if it's not open." :D

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Wisdom

## UbuntuWisdom.com

Available.

Comment: I think this is better than the current number of votes suggests!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Crowd

## UbuntuCrowd.com

Available.

Comment: sounds like a social network for diehard ubuntu fanboys

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu Knowledge

## UbuntuKnowledge.com

Available.

Answer (score -2):

Ubuntu-Wise

## Ubuntuwise.com

Available.

Answer (score -2):

support.ubuntu.com

## support.ubuntu.com

but it sounds like professional support :(

Answer (score -2):

exchange.ubuntu.com

Answer (score -2):

## ubuntusexchange.com

In ref to UbuntuExchange.com and the ill-thought expertsexchange.com

Comment: +1 on this because its funny on many levels. Do not count this as a vote of me wanting this domain though.

Comment: Exactly.  Is it different than ExpertSexChange.com -- sorry for the caps.

Answer (score -3):

## osforhumans.com

## osforhumanity.com

*Both available.*

Comment: nice domains...

Comment: isnt this the slogan for Ubuntu?  I liked it although askubuntu.com does seem more aporpriate now that I see it

Answer (score -3):

Ultimate Ubuntu

## UltimateUbuntu.com

Available.

Comment: Ubuntu ultimate is another distro

Answer (score -3):

Ubuntu Junction

## UbuntuJunction.com

Available.

Answer (score -3):

All Ubuntu

## AllUbuntu.com

Available.

Answer (score -3):

How about something like

### UbuntuJustWorks.com

A reference to the Apple claim that their stuff "just works". Linux certainly doesn't "just work." But here, any mess you're in trying to get Ubuntu to work is solved.

Just an idea. And, it's available.

Answer (score -4):

Expert Ubuntu

## ExpertUbuntu.com

Available.

Answer (score -4):

Uber Ubuntu

## uberubuntu.com

available

Comment: sounds like a fanboy site

Answer (score -4):

Inspired by the *adjective animal-noun* meme suggested by McDowell, I thought of the

### purplepenguin.com

but there is a [site using that name](http://purplepenguin.com) already :/ though it still has "lorum ipsum" text all over the place, so they may yet go bust and leave the domain free ...

There is also an existing http://orangepenguin.com/ but http://auberginepenguin.com/ is available, though it is doesn't trip off the tongue the way purple does ...

Comment: Do you mean http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=purple%20penguin ?

Answer (score -4):

**linux4humans.com**

I like this one. As a bonus it goes with the Ubuntu human theme (both philosophy and ui) :)

Answer (score -5):

MAN Ubuntu

## MANUbuntu.com

Available.

Comment: man as in manual... i'd give it +1 but this isnt really a manual

Answer (score -5):

Thinking a little more about alliterative penguins

### ProlificPenguin.com

Not as ubuntu specific as the purple penguin, but might still be OK ... It does have the advantage of being available.

Answer (score -5):

HolyCrapICanFinallyOpenAnExcelFile.com

I figured people have issues with getting up and running with ubuntu. I was going to suggest

UbuntuMadeEasy.com

But that has no umph to it.

Answer (score -7):

**buntubuntu.com** is available, at least according to `whois`.

I think its neat, because it can be read as 'buntu buntu' , or 'bunt ubuntu' (probably depending on how frustrated you might be at the moment).

Comment: -1 for being extremely hard to spell

Comment: buntbuntubuntubuntu :o