# We now have control of @askubuntu on Twitter - what should do with it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

These are all related:

- [Help spread this site....](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/171/help-spread-this-site)
- [Improving our presence on Twitter](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/772/improving-our-presence-on-twitter)
- [Should we target Social Media?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/280/should-we-target-social-media)

Thanks to Robert at Stack Exchange, Jorge and I now have access to [@askubuntu](http://twitter.com/askubuntu) on twitter (and I'm going to email the other mods with details here shortly).

Something that was mentioned at UDS-Q was that @stackubuntu was "weird". Should we formally request that Stack Exchange rename @stackubuntu to @askubuntu?

It's already been done for [Apple.se](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/using-the-stackapple-twitter-account), so I don't think it should be that much of a issue.

Comment: Lets try to do better than the [@sweden twitter](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-18423780) account, yes?

Comment: @Tom the Sweden account is funny! Ok, will do. ;)

Comment: Do you still have control over this?

Comment: @Seth I'm not sure I do... checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StackUbuntu has been renamed AskUbuntu, as per your requests. :D

Answer (score 8):

For branding issues @stackubuntu *needs* to be renamed to @askubuntu We've done an excellent job from the get go of pushing the name Ask Ubuntu, a lot of people know and are familiar with it. To continue to use stackubuntu would be hinder our branding and image in the social networking realm.

Comment: Agreed. So what I'm suggesting is that SE rename the current askubuntu to something else, and then they can rename stackubuntu to askubuntu.

Comment: Yup! Sounds good to me.