# Ask Ubuntu vs AskUbuntu

Tags: discussion, site-attributes

What's the name of our site?

AskUbuntu seems to be more popular currently, but that could just be that it gained some initial momentum somewhere.  Our [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq), however, says:

> **AskUbuntu** is a Q&A site...

The [name answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1/what-should-our-com-domain-name-be/7#7) says Ask Ubuntu, which is also how the site is identified when logging in via a Launchpad OpenID (and maybe others? haven't checked).  Stack Exchange convention is to use a space for the site name, and site names generally look better that way.

Personally, I'd rather see **Ask Ubuntu**, but it's not a big deal and I've been going with what has seemed the more popular choice.  On the other hand, there are still many users who use StackOverflow rather than Stack Overflow, and if the currently most popular SE site gets that, certainly we will too.

On the gripping hand, it is important to have a consistent face, even if which option is used doesn't matter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The *proper* way to write the name of the site is **Ask Ubuntu**.

This is derived from our Trademark Guidance for all Stack Exchange sites:

[**Legal > Trademark Guidance**](http://meta.askubuntu.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

> *Stack Overflow* is a programmer Q&A site on the Stack Exchange Network. As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters). The website domain name is always written "stackoverflow.com" (no CamelCase, single word capitalization rules apply). Currently, **all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention**: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User (superuser.com), etc.

This would include the name **Ask Ubuntu** with the domain name written as **askubuntu.com**.

Comment: Need we worry about domain name camel case? IIRC domain names are case-insensitive.