# Add a space to "Google description"

Tags: bug, status-completed

If I Google "Ask Ubuntu" the sites description says:

> AskUbuntu is a collaboratively edited
>   question and answer site for people
>   who love Ubuntu. It's 100% free, no
>   registration required.

There should be a space in the site's title per [this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/565/ask-ubuntu-vs-askubuntu).

(I [would also like](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/591/site-title-name) the title tags on all site pages to be changed from "Ubuntu - Stack Exchange" to "Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, we're making these changes now.