# Site <title> name

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, promote

All the sites pages have **Ubuntu - Stack Exchange** in their title.

I believe this should be changed to **Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange** (or even simply **Ask Ubuntu**).

This will help with branding our site on the internet.

Comment: Sounds logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This was done](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/590/add-a-space-to-google-description/613#613).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the page titles (for *all* new SE sites) currently show the topic rather than the site name as a matter of course.

This is a branding issue that I believe hasn't been given too much attention yet, but should be done consistently across all SE sites (once they get out of beta, anyway).  We, the users, would like to build Ask Ubuntu's identity and SOInc. (that is, the company Stack Overflow Internet Serives, Inc.) is also trying to build Stack Exchange's identity — those aren't mutually exclusive goals, but you do have to consider both concerns.

Comment: I understand this completely. Ask Ubuntu is in an unusual situation - it is the only "new" SE site with an actual name! I think having **Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange** in the title is an excellent compromise because it helps promote both brands - and enables them both "to be Googleable".