# Remove Stack Exchange from title

Tags: feature-request

Since Ask Ubuntu has a dedicated domain name, shouldn't the "Stack Exchange" part be removed from the title? Other SE sites with a dedicated domain already do this.

Titles of other SE websites with a dedicated domain:

- [Super User](http://superuser.com)
- [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
- [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Titles of SE websites on the stackexchange.com domain:

- [Pro Webmasters - Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)
- [Programmers - Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

This question is related to [Site <title> name](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/591/6969), but this question specifically targets the `Stack Exchange` part of the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this will happen anytime soon. We're still a child of the Area51 StackExchange service. As such our branding would likely remain the same.

This site started as a community effort on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu) The Trilogy sites were launched prior to the existence of Stack Exchange. Just because we have a full name does not change our lineage. We're no more different than Programmers, Pro Webmasters, Gaming, etc.