# Is it possible for a mod to "globally" change "AskUbuntu" to "Ask Ubuntu"?

Tags: discussion

It's not a big deal but it would be nice if existing occurrences of "AskUbuntu" were changed in questions and answers because [Ask Ubuntu is official](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/565/ask-ubuntu-vs-askubuntu). Or people could do so when they come across "AskUbuntu" but wouldn't that be a trivial edit, assuming there's nothing else to fix in a question or answer?

Comment: If you want you can start editing instances manually, and editing the rest of the question/answer of course, searching for misspellings, formatting, tags. There are 12 pages right now... http://askubuntu.com/search?q=askubuntu

Comment: @mateo_salta, but what if there is nothing else to fix? It then becomes a trivial edit.

Comment: then don't fix it, not like it's the end of the world...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish. [You can try this](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/92703/askubuntu). [Or this](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntumeta/query/92703/askubuntu)?

Comment: But this is the most minor of edits... Bumping questions around just to add a space should not be done.

Comment: @Marco Ceppi, Thanks but it's way beyond me. I don't know programming at all :(

Comment: @Oli, that's why I did just one and stopped. I thought if there's some way the system could handle it then that would prevent a rash of edits for something trivial.

Comment: +1 @Oli this post is to point out that if a question has askubuntu in it there's a good chance the rest of the question could require edits. Never make or submit an edit just to fix this one word.

Comment: A script I wrote did that for tags. It isn't logical because of the captcha

Comment: Please don't script things against the site. If it's really a problem (150 questions is not a real problem) then we can ask Stack Exchange for support.